# How do I create link of each word in d3 cloud?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tag-cloud

I am using [D3 Cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) to build a word cloud. Here is the sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="../lib/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script src="../d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
<script>
  var fill = d3.scale.category20();

  d3.layout.cloud().size([300, 300])
      .words(["This", "is", "some", "random", "text"].map(function(d) {
        return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 90};
      }))
      .padding(5)
      .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
      .font("Impact")
      .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .on("end", draw)
      .start();

  function draw(words) {
    d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 300)
        .attr("height", 300)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
      .selectAll("text")
        .data(words)
      .enter().append("text")
        .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
        .style("font-family", "Impact")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
        })
        .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
  }
</script>
```

I want to create a hyperlink on each of the words("This", "is", "some", "random", "text"). So in the word cloud, when I click on each of the words, it goes to the link. 
1) How do I function on each word?
2) Bonus if you could tell me how to change the size of the cloud to 800*300 instead of 300*300. As I have tried to change it's size in line "d3.layout.cloud().size([300, 300])" but it doesn't help. The text goes out of the box.

Hope you understood my question.

Thanks.

Comment: To change the size of the word cloud you need the change `.attr("width", 300)` , `.attr("height", 300)` and `d3.layout.cloud().size([300, 300])`.

Comment: I tried it. It helps but sometime half of the text goes out of the box and other half stays inside.

Comment: Look at the JSfiddle. Try changing the width and height variables. I changed the answer.

Answer (score 15):

To make the words clickable all you need to do is set an `on.("click", function(...){...})` listener which opens a new tab. You can also add styling to the text to make it look like a link. Here is some code:

```
var words = [{"text":"This", "url":"http://google.com/"},
             {"text":"is", "url":"http://bing.com/"},
             {"text":"some", "url":"http://somewhere.com/"},
             {"text":"random", "url":"http://random.org/"},
             {"text":"text", "url":"http://text.com/"}]

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i].size = 10 + Math.random() * 90;
}

...
d3.layout.cloud()
  ...
  .words(words)
  ...
  .start();

function draw(words) {
    ...
    d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      ...
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      ...
      .text(function(d) { return d.text; })
      .on("click", function (d, i){
          window.open(d.url, "_blank");
      });
}
```

I changed the format to make the code more manageable.
To change the width and height of the image you need to change three values:

```
d3.layout.cloud()
  .size([width, height])

d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  ...
  .attr("transform", "translate("+ width/2 +","+ height/2 +")")
```

These attributes should be controlled by two variables to to keep the code simple.

[**Here is a fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/rQLST/79/)

Comment: @jennifer06262016 It is fixed now. Someone moved d3-cloud that's why it broke.

Comment: thanks for repairing the fiddle. It was exactly what I needed.